# View commits that make changes to subfolder

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Assume a repo called `drivers` which contain sub-folders, eg., `ath`, `b43`, `p54`, etc.

Without subtreeing (creating new repo), is it possible to view commits that applies to a specific sub-folder, eg., view all commits that made changes to `ath` sub-folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify the folder with [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log -- ath
```

From the man page:

```
[\--] <path>…
```

> Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that match the specified paths came to be. (See [Historization Simplication](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification))
>
> Paths may need to be prefixed with ‘`--`’ to separate them from options or the revision range, when confusion arises.