# Git commits that touch a subtree/subfolder

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree, cherry-pick, monorepo

I have a monorepo project `proj` using subtrees in a folder `sub` under `proj/sub`. I have made tons of commits that touch both `proj` and `sub`. How do I publish the relevant changes to upstream `sub` effectively?

Usually, I'd have to cherry-pick every commit using

`git cherry-pick -x --strategy=subtree -Xsubtree=sub/ commit-ref`

but I have made zillions of commits so this is unfeasible. How can I integrate the changes to `sub` at once? For instance, create one big squashed commit that would bring `sub` to the same state it is in my monorepo.

Related: [View commits that make changes to subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002956/view-commits-that-make-changes-to-subfolder), [How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Current solution: mostly rebase

A few rebases with a couple of cherrypicks will do, but so far I haven't found an automated way using a single command. Use

```
git rebase -s subtree -Xsubtree=sub --onto sub_master proj_ini proj_end
```

to copy onto the subproject master branch `sub_master` all toplevel `proj` commits from ref `proj_ini` (exclusive) to ref `proj_end` (inclusive). The branch where you are at doesn't matter. For each commit, these things may occur:

1. Commits that touch only the subproject `sub` will be copied cleanly
2. Commits that touch only files outside `sub` will not show up. Since we are rebasing, these are silently ignored. If you would cherry-pick this
   type of commit, an error will occur telling that empty commits are not
   allowed (future Git versions may have `git cherry-pick --skip-empty`)
3. Commits that have changes to both `sub` and outside it will be
   copied with the exact same message, but with only the relevant changes/files kept, the rest being cleanly ignored
4. Renames/moves from `proj` to `sub` are cleanly rewritten as creations
5. Merge commits are mostly cleanly accounted for, with some exceptions

   5.1 Explicitly ignore the latest merge commit you did to the `proj` master coming from `sub`.

   5.2 Explicitly merge certain merge commits that had involved conflict resolution, using a cherrypick (current branch must be `sub_master`):

   ```
    git cherry-pick -x --strategy=subtree -Xsubtree=sub -m 2 merge_ref
   ```

   where `-m` is usually 1 or 2 for each parent. (In practice I will blindly try either one and `git cherry-pick --abort` and try the other if I get conflicts or unwanted changes)

Answer (score 2):

since cherry-pick can actually take in multiple commit-ishes, could you just do `git log [<options>] [<revision range>] -- sub` and format the output to just print hash sums?  Feed the list into `git cherry-pick -x --strategy=subtree -Xsubtree=sub/ <list of commits>`.  Are you just trying to accomplish this task with fewer commands?  If so, it might work, though I've never done it personally.

Comment: cherry pick a range wasn't as good as rebasing mainly because it will currently fail if any commits in the range result in empty commits to `sub`

Comment: and I could not get comfortable with blindly feeding a list from `git log` from a highly nonlinear history full of merges into cherry-pick